# Migrate from personal Google to GSuite

Tags: google-account, google-workspace-for-business

I’ve been using Gmail for almost 15 years, including many Google products linked to that same account.

I’ve now created a GSuite account, and I want to migrate as much as possible to that new account.

The GSuite dashboard allows me to transfer emails so that’s good. But what about all the other Google products? And what about browser history, location history, etc? I’m sure I will gradually discover products and data that will be out of sync ...

Is there a feature somewhere to just transform my gmail into a GSuite? 
If not, then a guide to get as close as possible ...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an one-click feature to transfer all data from a Google common account to a G Suite account. The official doc for G Suite administrators about this is [Transfer data between G Suite accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297?hl=en). This doc includes instructions for:

- G Mail
- Google Analytics
- Google Calendar
- Google Contacts
- Google Drive
- Google Sites
- Youtube

For other products, the above help article refers to the doc for end users [Download your data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en)

Comment: For the "other products" section, I'm not sure I understand how the download data helps. What do I do with this raw data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ways to sync Chrome browser information refer to my response on [Sync Chrome with personal G Suite account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122997/201028) which I answered recently describing options there on how you can transfer data from a Gmail account to you G Suite account.

If you need to transfer Drive data to your new G Suite instance and preserve file IDs and file history then you will need to leverage Team Drives in your G Suite instance to move files from your Gmail account to there. The challenges with this will be that folder IDs will change as you move them to a Team Drive. Any files that were shared due to inherited permissions from a folder will drop that individual when moving to a Team Drive. A user that was added directly to a file will still be able to access the file in the new Team Drive location as long as [Sharing with non-members](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7662202) have not been enabled. [Some file types](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337638) also can't be stored in a Team Drive.