# Sync Chrome with personal G Suite account

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace-for-business, synchronization, g-suite-administrator

I changed my gmail to a personal G Suite account. I'm the only user and the main reason was to have my personal domain with the G Suite (+ some of the benefits with storage).

However I'm struggling with an issue regarding syncing between my work laptop and home laptop. Both running Chrome. Both has been logged into same account (the G suite account) but I keep getting some message saying that my account is managed by my G Suite (personal-domain.com) and I can link data but not syncing (or something to that effect) so even though it is the same profile, same profile image and name, it does not sync tabs, extensions, bookmarks, etc. as it would do with a "normal" Google account.

I've checked the Chrome Service Settings at admin.google.com and it is marked as "ON for everyone" and as far as I can tell the settings within /admin/Device Management/Chrome/User Settings isn't disallowing any syncing of data.

Guess what I really need is to just let the chrome settings act as a regular Google/Gmail account and sync everything between my two laptops (and Android but that seems to work, at least with the bookmarks and Open Tabs).

Can anyone help me? Perhaps I'm missing something in G Suite admin area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to manage multiple Google profiles is by adding People to Chrome so that you can keep each profile separate and essentially avoid the challenge you're facing now.

Chrome allows you to sync data to a single Google account. When you signed into Chrome you synced with your gamil account. You now seem to have logged into another device first with your G Suite account and used that as the synced account.

You now have a few options.

On the device with Chrome synced with Gmail you can either sign out of your Gmail account for sync, then sign back in with your G Suite and decide to link the content that is stored in your Gmail account. Doing so will mean that both devices now sync to the G Suite account and data in your Gmail account no longer is updated.

Or you can create a new Person on that device with the Gmail Chrome profile and sign in with your G Suite account. This keeps your G Suite and Gmail profiles separate and only data that you have from the other device with the G Suite account will move to this device. You can equally make a Gmail profile on that work device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't get my head around that it isn't really an option to add same account in chrome on multiple devices without having to signin with a gmail account. It seem that it should just work out-of-the-box. I've completely removed all traces of my old Gmail account and signed in on both devices with my G Suite account but as you say the problem is still there probably because it is the same account and Chrome can't distinct between them. Thanks for your answer